# How vulnerable is 10.6 Snow Leopard to hacking?

Tags: virus, hacking

My 2007 Mac Mini is used as a TV media device, for watching free-to-air TV channels and Youtube. It cannot be upgraded past 10.6.8.

I read somewhere that older OS X can be vulnerable to unnoticed outside hacking, cannot find the reference anymore. Is this so? Is there a way to detect?

Comment: I didn't even know the security stack existed: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120453/os-x-10-6-and-known-unpatched-vulnerabilities You're getting down to the rare end of devices in terms of preferred targets. I'd prefer *not* to do what your doing (my 2007 mini is a non-wifi music server) but if I needed to I'd do it. Firewall up, no sensitive info on Mini, make sure to use something other than old-timey Safari as your browser. A once a week disk restore from unplugged, known clean, backup drive might ease your legitimate, yet rather unlikely worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a variety of exploits available. Though there's no one complete list, there's certainly a variety (see [this one](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-49/product_id-156/version_id-111857/Apple-Mac-Os-X-10.6.8.html)), including [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)#CVE-2014-6277), a remote exploit in Bash, and [SeaPea](https://wikileaks.org/vault7/document/SeaPea-User_Guide/), a root exploit. Apple will not patch these issues, as [Snow Leopard is no long supported in any capacity.](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2487996/malware-vulnerabilities/apple-retires-snow-leopard-from-support--leaves-1-in-5-macs-vulnerable-to-at.html)

While if you're careful, Snow Leopard isn't the end of the world, if you're concerned even remotely about security, given your use case of TV and YouTube, it probably makes more sense to just load up Windows or Linux and roll with that.